# Modify instead of add a class in classes_array for theming purposes

Tags: theming

I am using the following preprocess in my template.php

```
function paddle_admin_preprocess_menu_block_wrapper(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['delta'] === 'management_level_2') {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'max-width';
  }
}
```

It works as intended, it adds a class when the delta equals this string..

I am trying to modify another other entry of the classes_array array in order to make the classname more semantic. How would I go for that? (so replace an entry instead of add)

ps: I figured it can be as easy as:

```
$variables['classes_array'][1] = $variables['delta'];
```

but I am wondering whether the array indexes can change (from the ones I see with devel themer)

Answer (score 1):

Search for the key of the value you want to replace and then modify it. It's that simple.

```
function paddle_admin_preprocess_menu_block_wrapper(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['delta'] === 'management_level_2') {
    // Search for the key
    $key = array_search('class_to_be_replaced', $variables['classes_array']);

    // If class was found, replace it
    if ($key !== FALSE) {
        $variables['classes_array'][$key] = 'class_that_replaces';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I just did   $variables['classes_array'][1] = $variables['delta']; (I had a look with the devel themer and I know the one I'm trying to change is on the [1] location) would it be a safe thing to do? PS: your solution has one tiny issue: this class name has a variable part so I can't make a static string about it

Comment: If you are sure that no other modules will modify the classes array, then yes. Personally I would go with a more safe solution by searching for the key. If your class name is a variable, you can replace the string by it. You can also concatenate a string with a variable.

Comment: If you enable or disable modules, then the index may change.  Searching is safest.